# How many times did Satchii say "Boku Satchii!" throughout the series?

Tags: dennou-coil

The virtual robots that cleans up outdated space and illegal objects called Satchii, arrive in a similar manner: before they start shooting erasing beams at animate objects like people and virtual pets, they announce *"Boku Satchii!"* or "I'm Satchii!" (slightly distorted Japanese transliteration of the English word *search*). How many times, throughout the 26 episodes of anime series, do these robots announce their arrival?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extracting all subtitle files and looking for the name "Satchii", it looks like there are a total of 120 mentions of their name, and 20 times it's themselves announcing their arrival:

<sub>(Click for full size)</sub>
[image]

Comment: As an NLP dabbler, I'm curious: did you find out which ones were the bots referring to themselves just by reading all the lines, or did you have some ultra-cool analysis tool that built a statistical model of self-announcement in the Fansub English language based on Markov chains, with maybe a support vector machine tossed in for good measure, with some k-fold cross validation to ensure the error rate was acceptable? Either way, +1 for a clever question and answer.