# Did Vegeta ever called Goku his earth name "Goku" in Japanese dub?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series

I recalled that Vegeta once said "Goku" in episode 72 of English dub. Does Vegeta said his earth name "Goku" in Japanese dub too? How many times did Vegeta said "Goku" throughout the series? And when is it?

Comment: Get all the episodes with subtitles, extract the subtitle files, do a text file search and you'll get your answer. Like so: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22198/191

Comment: I don't thnk he ever does, as he rejects Goku's earthling name, which is the reason why enve when they fuse into Vegeto, the name uses Kakaroto's "to" in the name.

Answer (score 1):

1) When fighting against Nappa and Vegeta, Krillin laments on Goku hurrying up to get to the battlefield. Vegeta retorts, "Goku? Is he strong?"

2) When questioning Trunks' claim of being a SSJ, (IIRC) Vegeta's says something along the lines of "the one you call Goku.".

3) A Japanese title, "Koeteyaru... Gokuu wo!! Sentou Minzoku Saiya-jin no Ou". Or "I Will Surpass Him... Him, Gokuu! The King of the Fighting Race, the Saiyans". Or Mr. Simmons' translation, "I Will Overcome Goku!! The King of the Saiyan Warrior Race".